# How can I use merge method in Java to append elements to the list value in map<Character,List<Integer>>?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to understand the merge method. I have a map of `<Character, List<Integer>>`. I want to add the indices to the list of the appropriate key. I want to use the merge method to do so. I tried the following method. I am getting `UnsupportedOperationException`. What is the best way to do so using the `merge` method?

```
Map<Character, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    int t = i;
    map.merge(s.charAt(i), Arrays.asList(t), (c, list) -> {
        map.get(s.charAt(t)).add(t);
        return c;
    });
}
```

Comment: works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `Arrays.asList(t)` into `new ArrayList<>(...)` to allow its resizing. [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) is just a fixed size wrapper that doesn't support adding elements.

```
Map<Character, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    int t = i;
    map.merge(s.charAt(i), new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(t)), (c, list) -> {
        map.get(s.charAt(t)).add(t);
        return c;
    });
}
```

Note that as another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69611803/3764965) says, `merge` can be replaced with `computeIfAbsent`.

If you are into streams, you can use mutable reduction:

```
Map<Character, List<Integer>> resultMap = IntStream
    .range(0, s.length())
    .collect(
        HashMap::new,
        (map, i) -> map.computeIfAbsent(s.charAt(i), ch -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i),
        HashMap::putAll
    );
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks mate..I thought list created by Arrays.asList is resizable.

Comment: Note that the loop could have used `map.computeIfAbsent(s.charAt(i), ch -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i)` too, instead of working around the fact that `merge` is not the right tool for the job. But even if you stay with `merge`, it makes more sense to use `(list1, list2) -> { list1.addAll(list2); return list; }` as merge function.

Comment: …and you’re reinventing the wheel, i.e. the `groupingBy` collector, here, `Map<Character, List<Integer>> resultMap = IntStream.range(0, s.length()) .boxed() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s::charAt));`

Comment: That's right. `groupingBy` is also a good choice. I've missed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `computeIfAbsent()` instead of `merge()` like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcdabcdea";
    Map<Character, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(s.charAt(i), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

output:

```
{a=[0, 4, 9], b=[1, 5], c=[2, 6], d=[3, 7], e=[8]}
```